# How do I split a whitespace delimited string of tokens with an escape character?

Tags: php, regex

I need to tokenize a whitespace delimited string like `hey 'this is' some text` into an array `['hey', 'this is', 'some', 'text']` (single quote character being the escape character).

What I have so far will split on whitespace, but it doesn't incorporate the necessary escape character.

```
$tokens = preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $whitespaceDelimitedString);
```

Regular expression ninjas, come forth!! Please and thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$s = "hey 'this is' some text";
$a = preg_split("/'([^']*)'\s*|\s+/", $s, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($a);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hey
    [1] => this is
    [2] => some
    [3] => text
)
```

Comment: seems to fail if the quote is on the last character: `"hey this 'is some text'"`

Answer (score 3):

There's a built in PHP function for this: `str_getcsv()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

So this simple code:

```
<?php

$string = "hey 'this is' some text";

$output = str_getcsv ( $string, ' ', "'");

print_r($output);
```

...will output:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => hey
>     [1] => this is
>     [2] => some
>     [3] => text
> )
> ```

Comment: This doesn't work for all whitespace characters though, does it?

Comment: Just looking for [space] character in this case. If your source string  has random white space, you'd have to replace it first, I'd imagine.